# Why ConcurrentHashMap.putifAbsent is safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have been reading for concurency since yesterday  and i dont know much things... However some things are starting to getting clear...
I understand why double check locking isnt safe (i wonder what is the propability the rare condition to occur) but volatile fixes the issue in 1.5 +....
But i wonder if this occurs with `putifAbsent`

like...

```
myObj = new myObject("CodeMonkey");
cHashM.putIfAbsent("keyy",myObj);
```

Then does this ensures that `myObj` would be 100% intialiased when another thread does a `cHashM.get()` ??? Because it could have a reference isnt completely initialised (the double check lock problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you invoke `concurrentHashMap.get(key)` and it returns an object, that object is guaranteed to be fully initialized.  Each put (or putIfAbsent) will obtain a bucket specific lock and will append the element to the bucket's entries.

Now you may go through the code and notice that the get method doesnt obtain this same lock.  So you can argue that there can be an out of date read, that isn't true either.  The reason here is that value within the entry itself is volatile.  So you will be sure to get the most up to date read.

Comment: So if i understand correctly there is no problem ,like in the classic double check locking paradigm ?

Comment: @Parhs: Right, there is no problem.

Comment: You are correct.  You actually answered it yourself in your question with 'but volatile fixes the issue in 1.5 +'  Since the value returned from the CCHM is a volatile value, it too is safe from partial initialization.

Comment: @JohnVint I have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831817/how-to-make-concurrent-hash-map-thread-safe-with-get-and-put-as-an-atomic-operat) on performing get and put  operation atomically on CHM. Can you help me out over there?

Comment: @david I answered your question there. The only time you'll need the check-then-set logic is if it needs to be memoized.

Answer (score 5):

`putIfAbsent` method in `ConcurrentHashMap` is check-if-absent-then-set method. It's an atomic operation. But to answer the following part: "Then does this ensures that myObj would be 100% intialiased when another thread does a cHashM.get() ", it would depend on when the object is put into the HashMap. Usually there is a happens-before precedence, i.e., if the caller gets first before the object is placed in the map, then `null` would be returned, else the value would be returned.

Comment: null to be returned wouldnt be a prb but a reference to a non fully constructed-initiliased object would be. (the problem with double check locking)

Comment: +1 Upvoted for "Atomic"
Atomic takes care of ordering of threads, So .put() method is not called twice
ConcurrentHashMap takes care of synchronisation of Writer .put() method threads

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the documentation is this:

> Memory consistency effects: As with
>   other concurrent collections, actions
>   in a thread prior to placing an object
>   into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value
>   happen-before actions subsequent to
>   the access or removal of that object
>   from the ConcurrentMap in another
>   thread.

-- [`java.util.ConcurrentMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)

So, yes you have your *happens-before* relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, but looking at the implementation of `Segment` in `ConcurrentHashMap` I see that the `volatile` field `count` appears to be used to ensure proper visibility between threads. All read operations have to read the `count` field and all write operations have to write to it. From comments in the class:

```
Read operations can thus proceed without locking, but rely
on selected uses of volatiles to ensure that completed
write operations performed by other threads are
noticed. For most purposes, the "count" field, tracking the
number of elements, serves as that volatile variable
ensuring visibility.  This is convenient because this field
needs to be read in many read operations anyway:

   - All (unsynchronized) read operations must first read the
     "count" field, and should not look at table entries if
     it is 0.

   - All (synchronized) write operations should write to
     the "count" field after structurally changing any bin.
     The operations must not take any action that could even
     momentarily cause a concurrent read operation to see
     inconsistent data. This is made easier by the nature of
     the read operations in Map. For example, no operation
     can reveal that the table has grown but the threshold
     has not yet been updated, so there are no atomicity
     requirements for this with respect to reads.
```